# Another Bongard crosses your path

Tags: pattern, visual, bongard

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62061/i-made-my-own-bongard-problem-fruit-flies) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/bongard-number-2-shoelace), I've made my own Bongard. The goal is to find the rule that the pictures on the left follow, but none on the right follow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that:

> The points are nails of infinite hight, which hold the objects they are on.

Then

> All the left objects can be separated of such sort that no "lines" cross each other.

But

> Not clear for left-bottom-left

Comment: Good job, you got it! To be more precise, you may assume that all lines may pass through each other, but lines may not pass through nails.